# How can I automatically refresh a pivot table in Excel 365 (web)?

Tags: office-365, pivot-table, excel-online

I found https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/refresh-pivottable-data-6d24cece-a038-468a-8176-8b6568ca9be2#ID0EBBF=Web, which says:

[image]

However, I don't see the PivotTable Tools on the ribbon, even after clicking in my PivotTable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Click on the pivot table.
2. Click on the PivotTable in the ribbon.
3. Click on Settings in the ribbon.
4. Scroll down in the settings.
5. Check "Refresh data on file open":

[image]

No idea how to automatically refresh a pivot table in Excel 365 (web) more frequently than just on file open. If anyone knows, please add another answer.